# Is there a way to upload file to EFS from local system using java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-efs

I am new to AWS EFS and trying to understand how EFS file upload works.
Is there a way to upload files to EFS from local machine **programmatically using java**?

Comment: Is it possible to upload a generated file from an AWS ECS instance to EFS?

Comment: While this is a different question, the answer is yes. You can mount EFS file systems to an ECS task. More on this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-mount-efs-containers-tasks/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EFS is only accessible from within a VPC. You **can't access it directly** from outside of AWS. So you would have to setup a **VPN connection** between home network and your VPC, and then mount EFS filesystem in your local computer.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin for the reply

Answer (score 2):

AWS EFS is a managed NFS service. Copying files from a local (on-premise) machine would require to `mount` it through a VPN connection or AWS Direct Connect. There is a guide for this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-onpremises.html).

Once this is done, you can access it just like any other mounted file system, either with Java or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @tasos for the reply.